# Generate a CSV file with combination of unique field and XML using spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading an XML into a spark Dataframe using com.databricks.spark.xml and trying to generate a csv file as output.

My Input is like below

```
<id>1234</id>
<dtl>
    <name>harish</name>
    <age>21</age>
    <class>II</class> 
</dtl>
```

My output should be a csv file with the combination of id and remaining whole XML tag like

```
id, xml
1234,<dtl><name>harish</name><age>21</age><class>II</class></dtl>
```

Is there a way to achieve the output in the above format.

your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Spark-CSV library ?

Comment: Yes, it did not work out.

Comment: Update your approach here

Comment: you can read xml by this : `val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
   .option("rowTag", "foo")
   .load("bar.xml")`

Comment: reading is not a problem for me. Writing it into a csv with custom format is an issue for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a plain RDD to load xml as text file using sc.textFile() without parsing.
2. Extract id manually with the help of regex/xpath and also try to slice RDD string using string slicing from start of your tag to end of your tag.
3. Once it's done you will have your data into map like (id,"xml").

I hope this tactical solution will help you...